# Printing Extended Character with Android to Zebra Printer

Tags: android, printing, zebra-printers

I am working with Zebra printer which EM220II. I am able to print text with ASCII but when I try to print extended characters using their CodePage I get small (T) in front of each character . For example If I want £ this.. And if I use correct code that I get T£.

I have spend 2 days on this..

Let me know you guys want code..

Comment: Can you provide the string you are sending to the printer?

Comment: @OviTisler I pass "Price : \x9c 12.00" which gives me "Price : t£ 12.00"

Comment: Changing code page worked like charm..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking out the "x" and used just "\9c"? You can also use "_" in place of the "\" as well (e.g., "_9c"). Hope this helps and isn't too late ^.^

Comment: I had to change the code page and it did work… Thanks for your answer.